# Как удалить первый элемент двусвязного списка, кратный 5? C#

Tags: c#, двусвязный-список

Как мне удалить первый элемент двусвязного списка, кратный 5?
Вот код. Не понимаю, что делаю не так. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
internal class Program
{
    public unsafe struct Double_List
    {
        public int Data;
        public Double_List* Next;
        public Double_List* Prev;
    };

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;

        Double_List* Head = null;
        Double_List* Last = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Для закінчення вводу, напишіть 0.\n Введіть елемент: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int count = 0;
        while (n != 0)
        {
            Double_List* Current = stackalloc
            Double_List[sizeof(Double_List)];
            Current->Data = n;
            Current->Next = null;
            Current->Prev = null;
            if (Head == null)
            {
                Head = Last = Current;
            }
            else
            {
                Last->Next = Current;
                Current->Prev = Last;
                Last = Current;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Для закінчення вводу, напишіть 0.\n Введіть елемент: ");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Кількість елементів в списку:{0}", count);
        Console.WriteLine("Виведення елементів з початку списку");
        Double_List* Cur = Head;
        while (Cur != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Cur->Data); 
            if (Cur == Head && Cur->Data % 5 == 0)
            {
                Cur->Prev->Next = Cur->Next;
                Cur->Next->Prev = Cur->Prev;// проблема в этой части кода, оно его просто напросто не удаляет
            }
            Cur = Cur->Next;
        }
        
        Console.ReadKey();
      }         
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ```Cur == Head && ``` - зачем?) И нехватает ```break``` после нахождения элемента

Comment: Меня крайне сильно смущает наличие указателей. Они тут действительно нужны? Неужто без них нельзя было сделать двусвязный список. А так, добавляете себе лишней мороки по операциям с памятью (в т.ч. очистка). В шарпе, в отличие от плюсов, CLR сам подчищает всю эту грязь

Comment: @Frehzy видимо C++ учил, а в шарпе по инерции такой синтаксис использует. Я уже раньше здесь видел такие вопросы и тоже с украинскими текстами и указателями в коде, и тоже про связные списки, видимо препод один и тот же. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1279687/373567), кстати.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать уже существующее решение со связанным списком. Всё необходимое здесь уже реализовано

```
        string[] words =
            { "the", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "dog" };
        LinkedList<string> sentence = new LinkedList<string>(words);

        var nodeToDelete = sentence.First(x => x.Length % 5 == 0);
        sentence.Remove(nodeToDelete);
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)